# flatten array of object with one loop

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have this array of object, I want to extract its ids.

```
const arr = [
    
    {
        "id": "1",
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "options": [
            {
                "id": "2.1",
            }
        ]
    },
]
```

I did this

```
const one = arr.map(ob => ob.id)
const two = arr.flatMap(ob => ob.options).map(ob => ob?.id).filter(Boolean)

console.log([...one, ...two])
```

which worked fine, it prints `['1',  '2', '2.1']` which is what I wanted but is there any simpler or shorter way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one possible approach - `.concat` onto an array of just the parent `id` property inside the mapper callback.

```js
const arr = [
    
    {
        "id": "1",
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "options": [
            {
                "id": "2.1",
            }
        ]
    },
];
const result = arr.flatMap(obj => [obj.id].concat(obj.options?.map(o => o.id) ?? []));
console.log(result);
```

Another is

```js
const arr = [
    
    {
        "id": "1",
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "options": [
            {
                "id": "2.1",
            }
        ]
    },
];
const toId = obj => obj.id;
const result = arr.map(toId).concat(arr.flatMap(o => o.options?.map(toId) ?? []));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: the 2nd one is cleaner, thanks! I think can use spread one liner as well.

Answer (score 2):

Recursive with foreach

```js
const arr = [{
    "id": "1",
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "options": [{
      "id": "2.1",
    }]
  },
]

const getResult = (array, result = []) => {
  array.forEach(val => {
    result.push(val.id)

    if (val.options) {
      result = getResult(val.options, result)
    }
  })

  return result
}

console.log(getResult(arr))
```

Answer (score 0):

This generic approach will extract all `id` fields, without you needing to specify the structure (such as the `options` key):

```js
const arr = [{"id":"1"},{"id":"2","options":[{"id":"2.1"}]}];
const f=o=>typeof o==='object'?Object.keys(o).flatMap(k=>k==='id'?[o[k]]:f(o[k])):[];
console.log(f(arr));
```